# SOAP/WSDL Web Services how to implement?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

I am trying to implement a SOAP/WSDL Web Service. I just have the

Service URL:
and a
User-Key:

So my question is:

Firstly how to connect to the Web Service to do something?
Do you know a good tutorial for that?
Is there in netbeans a wizard for wsdl?

Comment: thx for your comment!!! I know that I shouldn`t use stack overflow as an reputation engine, but I am really stuck at that problem and do not really know where to start??? Would you be so kind to give me a hint if you know more?...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718580/how-to-communicate-with-webservice/10722315#10722315

Comment: What do you mean by  "having Service URL"? Is there a web-service already and you are trying to create a client for that service ?

Comment: So...do you actually have access to a WSDL?  If so, you might try downloading SOAP-UI, creating a project with that WSDL, and then generating a web service request to see what you can do.

Comment: yeah thats my Problem! generating the web service request! i wsimported all the files from the wsdl service but creating the request is really hard cause firstly I cannot connect to the server...