# How to communicate with WebService

Tags: java, web-services

I have been working on a JAXB for parssing an xml document in Eclipse. Everything goes good with the marshaller. However I want to send the marshalled xml data as string to a webservice and see what is going on there. Accordingly I created a webservice project, provide the wsdl. 
Eclipse generated a wsdl package with 5 java classes.Ws_mx_BindingStub,portType.java, PortTypeProxy.java,Service.java,ServiceLocator.java. I have no idea what I can do with this classes and communicate with webservice. I am new to webservice and couldn't get a good tutorial. I appreciate if anybody can explain me the next steps. Big Thanks!

Comment: http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SOA Using Java web Services" Mark D. Hansen
This book provides the information about what is going on when webservice system is running .In addition to what you are seeing, It provides the low level working principles.
My advice to learn the webservice in detail is that you should learn how to create a web service, deploy and run at command propmt.

There are two generic way of creating a webservices.

1-buttom-up
-Create a web service via implementing using Java
-compile it
-deploy it
2-top-down
-learn XSD and WSDL creation
-create webservice from WSDL file
-compile, deploy and run it

Before using these steps you should select an Application Server such as Glassfish

Comment: Actually I am working on an already existing webservice and Wsdl.